# Red Out VPN connection in Network Manager [Ubuntu 16.04.2]

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, vpn

I'm currently using an Ubuntu 16.04.2 instance on AWS EC2.
I've setup the VNCserver for GUI and remotely connecting with TightVNC viewer.
When I'm trying to edit the Network Connections to add in a VPN connection, but when I try to, I get the fields red/greyed out (see below). Can anyone help me out here?

[Network Connections - Editing VPN Connections - Red Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJH8.png)

Comment: What kind of VPN are you using?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm using PureVPN